# Is it correct to say "quantitative zeal" to mean an enthusiasm for maths?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-requests

If one was wanting to say that someone had a passion/enthusiasm for something like mathematics, can it be said that "they have [a] quantitative zeal" or "they are full of quantitative zeal"?

I normally think of zeal to mean excitement or enthusiasm; however, I felt that saying something like: "they had a zeal for mathematics" seemed awkward, and I would probably look for something else if I couldn't use the first usage I mentioned.

Comment: why not mathematical zeal?

Comment: [*Quantitative*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative) isn't limited to describing mathematics, though.  Also, see Matt's comment.  :)

Comment: OK, sure. It could be anything prefixed to zeal. I just wasn't sure if it was correct to use it like that--[subject] zeal. I am more used to seeing "a zeal for [subject]". I was just trying to give a specific example to work with.

Comment: *Quantitative zeal* just sounds like somebody who’s into super-sizing everything.

Comment: Oh, right! Yes, that construction is fine.

Comment: _quantitaive zeal_ sounds either too metaphorical or like maybe you like accounting.

Comment: The only meaningful context I can see for *quantitative zeal* is an allusion to politicians and bankers who like to talk of [Quantitative easing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantitative_easing) They hope we won't realise that's really just a euphemism for "printing money", which has a bad name because everyone now realises it's just a trick for governments to steal money out of your pocket without overtly raising taxes. The people have £100; government prints another £10 and spends it; the people only have just over £90 of spending power left. All without being taxed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be clear and direct, you should say "a zeal for mathematics".

When I read your title, my first thought was that "quantitative zeal" meant "an excitement that can be measured". (Perhaps I was thinking of "quantitative analysis" in chemistry, which means measuring the amounts of each substance, as opposed to "qualitative analysis", where you identify what the substances are.)

Similarly, I think someone would take "mathematical zeal" to mean that his enthusiasm is precise. When we say that something is "mathematical" we usually mean "precise".

Of course am ambiguous phrase might be preferable if you want to be more poetic.

Answer (score 5):

First, *quantitative* is not the same as *mathematical*.

*Mathematical zeal* doesn't necessarily mean a zeal for mathematics. You don't want to describe the zeal itself, but what the zeal is directed towards.

You could have a *fiery* zeal, for example, but you would still need to say what he was zealous about.

Comment: Is that zeal for fire?

Answer (score 1):

In Quantitative zeal, 'quantitative' would be an adjective. It describes the type of zeal you are having, than what it is for. While your requirements are to show that the person in question has a zeal for 'something' and not of 'some kind'.

If you use quantitative zeal, - which doesn't make much sense - you will still have to write what the zeal is about.

Comment: The modifier *quantitative* is applied to the noun *zeal*.  That makes it an adjectival modifier here, not an adverbial one. I cannot think of a reasonable way for this instance of *zeal* to be used as a verb, adjective, adverb, or preposition, so I cannot think of a way for *quantitative* to be an adverb.  The adverb would normally be ***quantitatively***. I think you need to edit your answer to say “adjective” where you’ve written “adverb”.